# Ubuntu 14.10 won't connect to a captive portal but will in a vmware client on same machine

Tags: networking, 14.10, vmware

Okay I have Ubuntu 14.10 on an Acer c720 Chromebook and have a very strange question.  I haven't seen anything like it when searching so I'm asking.

I can't get any browser (firefox, Chrome) to bring up the sign in page on some local captive portal hosts.  I used to before they changed the captive portal to a new configuration.  I can however connect on VMware Player using a windows xp virtual machine.  I have to have the network settings in VMware Player to "Bridged connected directly to physical network" and it comes up fine in the vmware machine.  However even once authenticated in the virtual machine the Host Ubuntu 14.10 OS still won't bring anything up in the browsers even though the vmware player can.  (which is how I'm typing this up at the moment, in the WinXP vmware virtual machine)

This is perplexing to me why my vmware client is fine but the host OS can't.

I had installed 15.04 Kubuntu (which I prefer to unity) and it worked but 15.04 had some issues that I didn't feel like messing with right now so I went back to 14.10 and it still won't connect to my favorite local captured portal.  VMware does just like above.  I'll try the suggestion below the next time I go to that location.

Comment: Have you tried changing the user-agent of your browser to something more windowsy ? That could be a bug or some kind of filtering. Don't expect it to work in the host once you have authenticated in the guest. There could be cookies involved or anything else...

Answer (score 0):

sorry I haven't got enough reputation to comment but by using solsTice advice I managed to get a similar problem working on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, so thanks, here is what I did:

- Access the config setting via firefox : type about:config in the address bar, some window will come up about security hit ok I understand.

-Next you need to search for general.useragent.override if it doesn't exist left click screen go to new then string and call it general.useragent.override

-set the string value to : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0;  rv:11.0) like Gecko, effectively setting you up as IE 11

-At this point still nothing happened for me so I hit in an address without the http:// to call a page and bingo I got mozilla trying to redirect me simple click allow and away you go hopefully.

Hope this helped